# AWS iOS v2 Video uploading issue

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

After using AWS SDK for iOS v1 i was using [S3PutObjectRequest stream] property to upload video files to the s3 server.With new version of the AWS SDK for the IOS such property was removed. I found out that new version has few Classes that can handle it such as [AWSKinesis] am i right are this classes are suitable for uploading video to the S3 server?
If yes could someone provide some examples please.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For people that what to use AWSKinesis lib is available nice tutorial.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/kinesis.html

Comment: Video uploading is not a typical use case for Amazon Kinesis. As noted [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/dev/service-sizes-and-limits.html), the maximum size of a data blob (the data payload after Base64-decoding) is 50KB.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `AWSS3TransferManager` for uploading movies to your S3 bucket. This [sample app](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/S3TransferManagerSample) demonstrates how to use the transfer manager.

Answer (score 0):

```
 self.s3 = [[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithAccessKey:ACCESS_KEY_ID   withSecretKey:SECRET_KEY];

NSError *error = nil;
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:tempPath options:nil error:&error];


S3PutObjectRequest *por = [[S3PutObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:@"Video Name"
                                                         inBucket:@"BucketName"];
//por.contentType = @"image/jpeg";
por.contentType = @"video/quicktime";
por.data = data;
por.delegate = self;


start = [NSDate date];
[self.s3 putObject:por];
```

Successfully uploaded then below method will call:

```
 -(void)request:(AmazonServiceRequest *)request didCompleteWithResponse:   (AmazonServiceResponse *)response
```

Failed to upload then below method will call:

```
  -(void)request:(AmazonServiceRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
```

Comment: Thx for the response but this is for AWS iOS sdk versions 1.